# What’s the thing with Ico spheres?

Tags: modeling, topology

I watch a lot of blender tutorials. And I see 80% of the time people rather use Ico spheres rather than UV spheres. Why is that? Is there a thing that I’m not seeing that UV spheres DONT have but Ico spheres do have?

Comment: Even geometry distribution

Comment: This article explains lots of things about topology that give you why some meshes are better than others in some regards: [ArtStation - How to use Ngons](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/0n93EV)

Comment: It's not always more interesting, it depends on what you want to do with your sphere, if you want to create a snowflake particle it maybe be lighter than a UV sphere because it needs less vertices